# black screen on Ubuntu 14.04 Install

Tags: boot, usb, ati, 64-bit

I am trying to install Ubuntu from a 4gb flash drive to another 16gb flash drive, both fat32 format. I am running an AMD radeon r7 250 and 16gb system RAM. When I select "try Ubuntu without installing" it shows the Ubuntu logo and stuff, GUI pops up, except there is major artifacts and stuff. I can't even see any text in the windows I open, except on the sidebar to the left....Now.....when I click Install Ubuntu, whether its normal mode or OEM mode, I get a completely black screen except for my mouse cursor, cant see ANYTHING other than that....I am new to Ubuntu so I don't know much about it, figured I'd delve into other OSes....if someone knows how to fix this it'd be much appreciated. Running a Kaveri x64 processor with Win7 already installed to a hard disk....monitor I'm using has a dvi-D and VGA/d-sub connector but only using the dvi port tho....if anyone has any help to offer Skype me: IrradiantMoon

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to boot with the boot-option

```
nomodeset
```

instead of

```
quiet splash
```

in the `grub menu`.